# How to access an Apollo Server Internal Kubernetes Service from my Web apollo-client exposed application with Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, apollo, traefik, apollo-client, apollo-server

I want to make my **Nuxt.js with apollo-client** to connect to my **internal Apollo-Server** on **Kubernetes**.

My nuxtjs with apollo-client app is exposed via **Traefik** Ingress and when i set my apollo-client URL to the `<service>.<namespace>` to point to my internal apollo-client i get the following error message on Chrome Console:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

My Apollo Server is running on port **6666** but my **Service runs on port 443 and targets port 6666**

**Apollo Config:**

```
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

// Replace this with your project's endpoint
const GRAPHCMS_API = process.env.API

export default () => ({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: GRAPHCMS_API }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultHttpLink: false
})
```

My **API variable:**

```
  API: "https://service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:443/gql",
```

Comment: Hi, can you paste your ingress yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Your Nuxt.js based web application needs to have access from outside to your Kubernetes' cluster workload: Apollo Server. This is because Nuxjs runs on client side (web browser), and it does not know anything about cluster internal DNS name "service.namespace.svc.cluster.local" given to backend service (Apollo Server) - these DNS names are resolvable only inside the cluster.

You need to expose your Appolo Server on NodePort or LoadBalancer type service, as explained in official doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport). Yet another option is to expose your "Apollo Server Internal Kubernetes Service" via Ingress too with [TLS/HTTPS](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/).